# jqGrid - disable page size dropdown

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net

I want to disable the paging but want to keep the plus button on the left. The picture below is what I end up with. There is still a drop down page size visible. I have already took out the paging option for that. But still...

[image: result]

Here is the code

```
jQuery("#detFlex101_1").jqGrid({
    url: root + mod + '/detaillistview',
    datatype: "local",
    colNames:[' ', '@Resources.Xdt_Parameter.param_display_name', '@Resources.Xdt_Parameter.param_tooltip_desc', '@Resources.Xdt_Parameter.param_data_type', ' ', ' ', '@Resources.Xdt_QueryParameter.qupa_required_flag', '@Resources.Xdt_QueryParameter.qupa_default_value'],
    colModel:[
        {name:'myac', width:80, fixed:true, sortable:false, resize:false, formatter:'actions', formatoptions:{keys:true, editbutton : false, delbutton : false, delOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false},editOptions: {reloadAfterSubmit:false}}},
        {name:'display_name',index:'display_name', width:100},
        {name:'tooltip_description',index:'tooltip_description', width:300},
        {name:'data_type',index:'data_type', width:100},
        {name:'parameter_id',index:'parameter_id', width:100,hidden:true},
        {name:'query_id',index:'query_id', width:100,hidden:true},
        {name:'required_flag',index:'required_flag', width:100},
        {name:'default_value',index:'default_value', width:100}
        ],
    width: $('.body').width()-40,
    height: 120,

    pager: '#pagerFlex101_1',
    rowList: [],        // disable page size dropdown
    pgbuttons: false,     // disable page control like next, back button
    pgtext: null,         // disable pager text like 'Page 0 of 10'
    viewrecords: false,   // disable current view record text like 'View 1-10 of 100'

    sortname: 'parameter_id',
    sortorder: "desc",
    editurl: root + mod + '/detailpost',
    caption:"@Resources.Xdt_QueryParameter.qupa_param_title",
    onSelectRow: function(id){
        activedf = "#detFlex101_1";
    },
    afterInsertRow: function () {
        var grid = $(this),
        iCol = getColumnIndexByName(grid,'myac'); // 'act' - name of the actions column
        grid.find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow>td:nth-child(" + (iCol + 1) + ")")
        .each(function() {
            if ($(this).find(">div>div").length == 2)
            {
                $("<div>",
                    {
                        title: "Delete",
                        mouseover: function() {
                            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        mouseout: function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        click: function(e) {
                            df_delete_1($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
                        }
                    }
                  ).css({float:"left"})
                   .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit")
                   .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-trash"></span>')
                   .prependTo($(this).children("div"));

                $("<div>",
                    {
                        title: "Edit",
                        mouseover: function() {
                            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        mouseout: function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        click: function(e) {
                            df_edit_1($(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
                        }
                    }
                  ).css({float:"left"})
                   .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit")
                   .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-pencil"></span>')
                   .prependTo($(this).children("div"));

                $("<div>",
                    {
                        title: "Up",
                        mouseover: function() {
                            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        mouseout: function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        click: function(e) {
                            jqGridMoveRow('up', grid, $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
                        }
                    }
                  ).css({float:"left"})
                   .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit")
                   .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-n"></span>')
                   .prependTo($(this).children("div"));

                $("<div>",
                    {
                        title: "Down",
                        mouseover: function() {
                            $(this).addClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        mouseout: function() {
                            $(this).removeClass('ui-state-hover');
                        },
                        click: function(e) {
                            jqGridMoveRow('down', grid, $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow").attr("id"));
                        }
                    }
                  ).css({float:"left"})
                   .addClass("ui-pg-div ui-inline-edit")
                   .append('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-arrowthick-1-s"></span>')
                   .prependTo($(this).children("div"));
            }
        });
    }
});

jQuery("#detFlex101_1").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerFlex101_1',{edit:false,del:false,search:false, addfunc: df_add_1});
jQuery("#detFlex101_1").jqGrid('gridResize', {minWidth:350, maxWidth:1920, minHeight:80, maxHeight:1080} );
jQuery("#detFlex101_1").jqGrid({pgbuttons:false, recordtext:'', pgtext:''});
```

Anyone know what to do?

Comment: Check here you may find lots of interesting answers about jQGrid http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:315935+[jqgrid]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The usage of virtual scrolling (`scroll: 1`) is not the same as no paging.

If you just need to have empty pager you need use some jqGrid options (see [the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3apager#properties)):

```
rowNum: 10000,      // !!! it's important to increase default 20 value
pginput: false,
pgbuttons: false,
rowList: [],        // it's default setting
viewrecords: false, // it's also default setting
```

The most important would be not forget to define `rowNum` with some large enough value. If you don't do this then only 20 rows from the first page will be displayed in the grid.

Answer (score 0):

you can use scroll option, define it in the jqgrid options. 
 **scroll:1**
By using this option, you are instructing the jqgrid not use pagination and in other words, you will be implementing a virtual scroll.
Hope it meets your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Just need to set gridoptions like below
rowNum: 1000,
rowList: [],
pgbuttons: false,
        pgtext : "",
pginput : false,
viewrecords: false,